# Is this a LEGO part? It looks very similar to a technic axle connector 2x3 with ball socket

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, clone-brands

I recently bought a bag of random LEGO pieces which contained some non-LEGO pieces. This piece looks a lot like a Technic axle connector 2x3 with ball socket ([32174](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32174#T=C) / [60176](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60176#T=C) / [93571](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93571#T=C) / [89652](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=89652#T=C)) but not quite the same as any of the pictures I found.

The main differences are the side isn't smooth but rather has two rectangular indentations (see picture 1) and the loops at the bottom have gaps in them (picture 2). The plastic doesn't show any signs that it has been snapped so I assume it was made like this.

I can't find any writing etched/stamped on it.

Does anyone know if this is a real LEGO piece and what its part number is if it is?

Thank you :)

Picture 1
[image: Picture 1]

Picture 2
[image: Picture2]

Comment: Another indication that this is not from LEGO is that you can see the marks left from the injection molding.  LEGO is usually smart enough to keep those on the inside of a part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a non-LEGO piece since none of the LEGO parts have gaps as seen in second picture.

One thing to note. Actual LEGO elements (depends on the version of Technic, Axle Connector 2 x 3 with Ball Socket) tend to crack right where the gap is on this clone element.